# Method/function return type in call stack

Tags: function, methods, callstack

I was trying to find the existence of return type constraint in method call stack. Event any language you use, (java / c++), we specify the return type of method/function. When this method enters into call stack (or in memory, I'm not sure) how does it uses our specified return type?

Another thing is why can't we specify two return types in header? like 
      public (int, float) myMethod(){
          return (1, 2.5);
      }

So this function could return two values (one int and one float).
I'm not asking here about returning more than one value from method. That off course i can do using array or creating a custom object. My question is, how this is mapped in the stack so that it take notice of return type constraint and why we can't specify more than one return type?

As you can see, the picture of call stack, I can't see anything about return type here.

[image: call stack]

So finally I summarize my question.

1) How will you modify this attached image to specify the return type and why?

2) I can not specify more than one return type in any language (that i know), why?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got it by myself.

First question:
1) How will you modify this attached image to specify the return type and why?

**Answer:** There is no point of return type in call stack. In many languages you don't even specify return type, like python, PHP etc. So there is no relation of return type with call stack.

2nd question:
2) I can not specify more than one return type in any language (that i know), why?

**Answer:** It depends on requirement. Language designer don't feel any need to return more than one value (Off course they provide alternate like returning array, but value returned only one, that is reference to array). If language designers feel the need to return two values, I think they can. But there is no need of that.